# Pass data from BroadcastReceiver to ViewModel or Repository

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, broadcastreceiver, viewmodel

I'm trying to send the data that I receive in the broadcast(registered in manifest) in the viewmodel or in the repository is not particularly important, I tried to do it both through the live date and through RxJava2, but there is data inside the broadcast class i can see, but it does not come to the viewmodel or repository, thank you.

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver  : BroadcastReceiver() {

private val dataList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Words>>()
private var observer: Observable<ArrayList<Words>> = Observable.just(arrayListOf())

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {



    val arrayObject =
        intent?.extras?.getParcelableArrayList<Words>("KEY") as ArrayList<Words>?
   
    dataList.postValue(arrayObject)

    arrayObject.let { dataList.postValue(it) }

    arrayObject.let { observer = Observable.just(it) }

    observer = Observable.create { emitter: ObservableEmitter<ArrayList<Words>> ->
            emitter.onNext(arrayObject!!)
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
}

fun getDataList() : LiveData<ArrayList<Words>> = dataList

fun getDataListRx() : Observable<ArrayList<Words>> = observer
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
class MyViewModel(
private val broadcastReceiver: MyBroadcastReceiver,
private val activity: DaggerActivity) : ViewModel() {

init {
    test()
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
private fun test() {
    broadcastReceiver.getDataListRx()?.subscribe({
        Log.d("WAS_INTENT", "DateRepSuccess")

    },{
        Log.d("WAS_INTENT", "DateRepError")

    })

    broadcastReceiver.getDataList().observe(activity, Observer {
        Log.d("WAS_INTENT", "DateRepSuccessLiveData")

    })
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I found out that the liveData works, so maybe someone will need it. RxJava still don`t , I don’t know why yet.